# jQuery .select() not working and how to get the node at caret?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to add style to a selection in a `contenteditable` `div`.

```
function textStyle( css ) {
    var sel, el, range, selectedText
    sel = window.getSelection()
    range = sel.getRangeAt( 0 )
    selectedText = range.toString()
    range.deleteContents()
    el = document.createElement('span')
    $( el ).css( css )
    el.innerHTML = selectedText
    range.insertNode( el )
    range = range.cloneRange()
    range.setStartBefore( el.firstChild )
    range.setEndAfter( el.firstChild )
    sel.removeAllRanges()
    sel.addRange( range )
}

$( '.bold' )
.on( 'click' , function() {
    textStyle({ 'font-weight' : 'bold' })
})

$( '.italic' )
.on( 'click' , function() {
    textStyle({ 'font-style' : 'italic' })
})

$( '.edit' )
.select(function() {
    console.log( $(this) )
})
```

The adding of the style is working. But now I want to have the same behaviour as Google Drive and have the button give a feedback to the user. So when I "put" the caret into a `bold` text part, I want the bold button to light up!!!

Is that done with jQuery? The `.select()` is not working for me? The docs say:

> Merely setting the location of the insertion point will not trigger the event.

*Edit:* In the end I want to simply be able to undo the styling and have a feedback for the user before that!

*Edit 2:* About the "missing" semicolons https://twitter.com/izs/status/493448367196741632.

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/UP4Mr/)

Comment: ``;`` is missing everywhere

Comment: @doniyor Hmm, do you have Google Drive? Or MS Word? If you place the caret into bold text, you will get the button for that highlighted. That's all for now. Just tell me how to get the `.select()` working. ;)

Comment: @doniyor I added a line about the outcomings I preferred.

Comment: you mean, the button ``B`` should stay pressed if in bold, if you debold, then stay unpressed, right?

Comment: @doniyor No, yahw, nearly. If you are typing somewhere in the field, the usual state should be unhighlighted. But as soon as you put the caret into a bold text, it should be highlighted (different background color). And the next step is to debold the "whole" bold text. Hope that helps. %)P

Comment: oh man, there are many libraries out there for this: http://nicedit.com/ will this be ok for your plan?

Comment: @doniyor No, sorry, it's for an own CMS. Can you help with getting this `.select()` listener working? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `select` is not going to fire for your `.contentEditable` div. You should be listening for `mouseup` (or `keyup` if you want to support people selecting things with the keyboard) and seeing if the selected text is the child of one of your styled `span` elements. Otherwise, switch to element that will fire your select events like `input` or `textarea`.

Comment: @NickTomlin Ah, thank you, that makes sense. It is not supposed to fire. I am just about the get the answer out of the nicedit.com `source code`. ; )

Answer (score 1):

I kinda did it; like this:

#### CSS

```
.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
}

.italic {
  font-style:italic;
}

.highlight {
  background: red !important;    
}
```

#### Javascript

```
var obj = {

    ndx : null

}

function textStyle( css ) {

    var sel, el, range, selectedText

    sel = window.getSelection()

    if ( sel.toString() != '' ) {

        range = sel.getRangeAt( 0 )

        selectedText = range.toString()

        range.deleteContents()

        el = document.createElement('span')

        $( el ).addClass( css )

        el.innerHTML = selectedText

        range.insertNode( el )

        range = range.cloneRange()

        range.setStartBefore( el.firstChild )

        range.setEndAfter( el.firstChild )

        sel.removeAllRanges()

        sel.addRange( range )

        $( 'input.Button.' + css )
        .addClass( 'highlight' )

    }    

}

function unStyle() {

    var node = $( '.edit span' ).eq( obj.ndx )
    , text = node.text()
    , range = document.createRange()

    range.selectNode(node[0])

    var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment( text )

    range.insertNode(documentFragment)

    node.remove()

}

$( '.bold' )
.on( 'click' , function() {

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'highlight' ) ) {

        unStyle()

        $( this ).removeClass( 'highlight' ) 

    } else {

        textStyle( 'bold' )

    }


})

$( '.italic' )
.on( 'click' , function() {

    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'highlight' ) ) {

        unStyle()

        $( this ).removeClass( 'highlight' ) 

    } else {

        textStyle( 'italic' )

    }

})

$( '.edit' )
.on( 'mousedown' , function( e ) {

    var span = $( e.target ).closest('span')
    , spanL = span.length

    obj.ndx = span.index()

    for (i = 0 ; i < spanL ; i++ ) {

        span = span[i].className

    }   

    $( 'input.Button' )
    .removeClass( 'highlight' )

    if ( spanL ) {

        $( 'input.Button.' + span )
        .addClass( 'highlight' )

    }

})
```

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/UP4Mr/9/)